# Filter an notification output live with JQ

Tags: powershell, jq

I've got a command. lets call it "gc listen".
That command send on powershell (windows) a stream that regulary send me a json string with some information. example :
`gc listen | jq -c '.eventBody.group.queueId'`

And, as you can imagine, it is not working as expected :D

1. the command `gc listen` is working correctly, i have every second a json like that

> {
> "topicName": "v2.analytics.queues.fzef-9208-4078-b012-fzegzeg.observations",
> "version": "2",
> "eventBody": {
> "group": {
> "queueId": "fzef-9208-4078-b012-fzegzeg",
> "mediaType": "voice"
> },
> "data": [
> {
> "interval": "2021-03-30T09:00:00.000Z/2021-03-30T09:30:00.000Z",
> "metrics": [
> {
> "metric": "nConnected",
> "stats": {
> "count": 1.0
> }
> },
> {
> "metric": "tAbandon",
> "stats": {
> "count": 3.0,
> "sum": 184416.0,
> "min": 41981.0,
> "max": 89420.0
> }
> },
> {
> "metric": "tHeldComplete",
> "stats": {
> "count": 12.0,
> "sum": 958886.0,
> "min": 9126.0,
> "max": 161639.0
> }
> },
> {
> "metric": "nOffered",
> "stats": {
> "count": 59.0
> }
> }
> }
> ]
> }
> ]
> },
> "metadata": {
> "CorrelationId": "7f3ef949-d85d-4cea-b92b-6d96b2915568"
> }
> }

2. if i save that on a file, and do : `type test.txt | jq -c '.eventBody.group.queueId'` i can get the queueId. And if i save multiple output of the first command, i got multiple id. no problem.
3. BUT when i try both on the same time, i don't have anything :

`gc listen | jq -c '.eventBody.group.queueId'`
with that command i, don't have anything.

4. it seems that in linux that command is orking correctly...

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried invoking jq with the `--unbuffered` option?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no it do not change anything